# How to use JObject.FromObject to get a json with no propertyname

Tags: json, json.net

I use NewtonSoft JSON.Net. I have a collection of namevalue pair and i need to get a json that looks like 
{"cot":"1","mac":"2","cot":"8"}
Note that i can have duplicate names here.

I have two options here
a) i can use Dictionary as my underlying collection and when i do, i get the desired result but i cant add duplicate key.
b) i have have a list of KeyValuePair but in this case, the result json is not in the structure i wanted.

Any idea how to get the desired result? thanks!

```
        var listData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        listData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("cot", "1"));
        listData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("mat", "1"));
        listData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("cot", "2"));

        var dicData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dicData.Add("cot", "1");
        dicData.Add("mat", "1");

        Console.WriteLine("Output from LIST");
        Console.WriteLine(JArray.FromObject(listData));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Output from Dictionary");
        Console.WriteLine(JObject.FromObject(dicData));
```

Output from LIST

```
[
  {
    "Key": "cot",
    "Value": "1"
  },
  {
    "Key": "mat",
    "Value": "1"
  },
  {
    "Key": "cot",
    "Value": "2"
  }
]
```

Output from Dictionary

```
{
  "cot": "1",
  "mat": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON 
`'{"cot":"1","mac":"2","cot":"8"}'` 
will parse to a javscript object :
`{"cot":"8","mac":"2"}`.

Try 
`dicData.Add("cot", "8")` 
and see if it gets what you want.

You can also try concatenating strings until you get the desired JSON.
Like

```
var jsonOutput = "{"
//for each key value...
jsonOutput += "key : "+ value.toString + ","
//...etc
//then remove the last trailing comma, and add a "}"
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. dicData.Add("cot", "8") will fail because cot is already a key in the dictionary. that said, i didnt realize that javascript will convert the JSON into a two item collection. Which in turn means i cannot solve this problem with the json format i chose. So it kind of answered my question. thanks :)!